# Searching column by empty string doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

First, I search column by some value e.g. FX1624. This value goes to TextBox, then I click 'Search'. My table is filtered by this value and it's ok.
After that I remove this value from textbox and click 'Search' as to search by empty values. And it doesn't work, no empty values are returned. How can I filter by empty/null values in this column?

**Controller:**

```
        public ActionResult XYZ(string account)
        {
            var docsModel = _docs.GetAll();
            var model = docsModel
                                   .Where(w => account == null || w.docsModel.ACCOUNT_NR == account)
                                   .Select(s => new DocumentsModel
                                   {
                                       Comp_name = s.docsModel.NAME,
                                       Decision_choice = s.docsModel.DECISION,
                                   })
                                   .OrderBy(o => o.docsModel.DATE);
            return View(model);
        }
```

**View:**

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm("XYZ", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
        {
            <th>
                    AccountName: @Html.TextBox("account")
                    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
            </th>
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are searching them model

```
.Where(w => account == null || w.docsModel.ACCOUNT_NR == account)
```

but what you'll be passing is an empty string, not null.

```
.Where(w => String.IsNullOrEmpty(account) || w.docsModel.ACCOUNT_NR == account)
```

The above should cover that

Comment: this .Where(w => String.IsNullOrEmpty(account) || w.docsModel.ACCOUNT_NR == account) would likely allow to create duplicates or overwrite the null or blank value entry. nothing wrong with this if the business model allows it, however perhaps reconsider this

Comment: @WalterVehoeven what do you mean by duplicates? I just filter data, that's it.

Comment: @Muska see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

regarding my comment, if you do it like the recommended answer you will iterate over all entries when null you'd just to return all while iterating overall, a rather "expensive" thing to do, just return all.

```
public ActionResult XYZ(string account)
{
    
    var data= string.IsNullOrEmpty(account)
                ?_docs.GetAll()
                :_docs.GetAll().Where(w => w.docsModel.ACCOUNT_NR.Equals(account, StringComparison.Ordinal);
                           
   var model = data.Select(s => new DocumentsModel{
                               Comp_name = s.docsModel.NAME,
                               Decision_choice = s.docsModel.DECISION,
                           })
                           .OrderBy(o => o.docsModel.DATE);
    return View(model);
}
```

I think you should consider altering the _docs.GetAll() method to not read all entries in memory after to then filter them, locking and bigger data sets could cause issues.

To answer your question using the sample you added in the comments

```
string[] inputs = { account, invoice, name };      
var filteredData = inputs.All(x => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
                 ? _docs.GetAll()
                 : _docs.GetAll().Where(w => w.ACCOUNT.Equals(account, StringComparison.Ordinal)
                                 || w.INVOICE_NR.Equals(invoice, StringComparison.Ordinal)
                                 || w.NAME.Equals(name, StringComparison.Ordinal));
```

also an IActionResult with all... data, are you missing paging?

Comment: Ok, looks interesting. And yes I have paging but doidn't show it here in my example. What does ```StringComparison.Ordinal```? Compares passed value 'aacount' with valaues in 'ACCOUNT_NR'?

Comment: I also have more filters in my code. E.g. I filter by customer name, dates etc. Should I do all filtering before  (assign outcome to var data as in example) and return outcome to var model?

Comment: @Muska, you can compare strings in several ways, a string is a number on a code page when you change the alphabet the number of a letter in the alphabet changes. string.Equals() allows you to chose how to compare the strings, google it you will see. Pagination is a way to returt a set of rows, from a whole table, you see it everywhere "page 1 of N" have a look at https://www.sqlshack.com/pagination-in-sql-server/. then in your site you I guess are doing something like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: I tried sth like this: ```string[] inputs = { account, invoice, name };

            var filteredData = inputs.All(x => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
                ? _docs.GetAll()
                : _docs.GetAll().Where(w => w.ACCOUNT.Equals(account, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                    .Where(w => w.INVOICE_NR.Equals(invoice, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                    .Where(w => w.NAME.Equals(name, StringComparison.Ordinal));```. If all arguments are nulls/empty then return all entries OTHERWISE return filtered dataset. Unfortunately it doesn't filter properly.

Comment: Did you intend to do this?
string[] inputs = { account, invoice, name };      
var filteredData = inputs.All(x => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
                 ? _docs.GetAll()
                 : _docs.GetAll().Where(w => w.ACCOUNT.Equals(account, StringComparison.Ordinal)
                       || w.INVOICE_NR.Equals(invoice, StringComparison.Ordinal)
         || w.NAME.Equals(name, StringComparison.Ordinal));

Comment: Yes. Do you think it's a good approach performance-wise? I mean to filter dataset separately based on parameters and assign outcome to variable - then pass it to model variable (as you showed in your answer)

Comment: @Muska, just think about the network and memory you need to do it all on your server, you will also be blocking less on the database as you transaction scope is smaller. if you do get all the data then you end up with the really old way of doing thing where all was loaded in DataTables, eventually you will run out of memory. also most ISP's only give you 500MB ram for your application. Not sure about your data volumes but I doubt it's sustainable to load all and then filter in code. Also, you application "freezes" when memory is freed by the garbage collector, nothing is "free"

Comment: I set some conditions when retrieving data from db. I don't get all data from db tables. I just want to filter data based on user's choice/search preferences. And this part is done in my code. But I think it would be good option to filter data everytime user search for sth and then pass outcome to model

Comment: @Muska I index in a database is like a separate list of data. If you look for all data where name == "a name" and you have an index on the name column the database will not do a row by row comparison something that is comparable to a dictionary lookup. Your Linq statements are the slowest and most ineffective way to look for data. Also do you need a case sensitive or case incentive compair? right now the string must match 100 %. perhaps you like to use string.StartsWith or string.Contains, these also have a StringCompair option

Comment: @Muska, are you using Entity framework? if so then look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/async

Comment: Hmm, the slowest possible way to look for a data, sounds bad. I'm rookie as you probably noticed. Yes, I use EF. Ok, could you please give me a hint or a link to where search an info about the most effective way of looking for data? I thought LINQ is best practice

Comment: @Muska We all started at the beginning, nothing wrong with that. Just use the code you do in Linq in the entity framework class, this will translate this in the right TSQL for you. also the OrderBy is definitely the thing you need to do on the entity class. I asume that  _docs.GetAll().Where() can be replaced with _docs.Where(). Did you look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: @Muska, in regards to linq have a look at https://mattwarren.org/2016/09/29/Optimising-LINQ/ Remember each class created memory allocated and data copied, and worst of all each class created is a class that needs to be garbage collected. Microsoft understood this when creating the ML framework where they created Tuple, Span<T> en other memory classes. Without this Microsoft ML would be even slower then it already is.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Linq in EF now, also OrderBy is done on entity class (method GetAll derives data from db). Thank you Walter, I'll take a look into lins you sent, my code needs to be enhanced for sure.

Comment: @Muska, all code needs to be improved, if I look at my old code in a code review and my name is not on it I'm also thinking "what the... "  https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.reddit.com%2Fr%2FProgrammerHumor%2Fcomments%2F1f9df7%2Fthe_only_valid_measurement_of_code_quality%2F&psig=AOvVaw2aoMYfC81lzDHhtD4dCsas&ust=1604075125785000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCMjkiNSb2uwCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD

Comment: In a few years I 'll say the same looking at my code I guess;)